# Swipe gesture not working properly for side bar menu - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uipangesturerecognizer, swrevealviewcontroller

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/) to create a side bar menu. I was able to successfully implement it and it worked perfectly. But when I added multiple table view,s I noticed that when I go from View 1 to View 2 (see the story board below) and then come back to View 1, I can't use the swipe gesture to open the side menu. The tap function does work, I can tap on the menu button and the menu slides out.

Below is the code that handles the swipe:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }
 }
```

When I swipe from left to right on the screen the above code produces the following result:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone have any clue why this is happening? I did research but could not find anything.
If you need more information or if the question is not clear enough please let me know.

Comment: Where did you put the code you've shown? `ViewDidLoad`?

Comment: @zcui93 yes in viewDidLoad sorry ill update my question. I Shouldve been more clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After messing around with the code I was able to fix the problem. Just to let you know I am not sure whether is the perfect solution there could be a better way of solving this. If so, please post it as an answer.

In the code above you can see I was putting the swipe gesture code within the viewDidLoad function.

After moving the swipe code to the viewWillAppear function the problem was fixed. Please see code below:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }
}
```

If you know of a better way of solving this or if this not the correct way of fixing this issue then please let me know.